# Read data in R Shiny App to run in Docker Container

Tags: r, docker, shiny, docker-container

I would like to publish my R Shiny App with the help of Docker Containers.
In the app, I have to read in some data (for example as a txt-file or an excel-file) and the app visualizes the data.
I am able to create a Container of a Shiny app that does not have to read external data, but as soon as I try to create a container of a Shiny app that has to read external data, I can not open the app in docker desktop.
The data which I need for my app changes constantly.
Does anyone have an idea how to handle this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount the data directory as a volume to the container:
`docker run -v /host_data_path:/container_data_path image_name`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Can I read my data in R Shiny in the usual way with for example read_excel (from the package readxl)?
Once I update my data, does the dashboard also automatically update the plots I make with the data?

Comment: Inside the docker image, there is a shiny server with a R session. If you install R packages inside this image, you can do everything what R can do. Docker is not a new programming language, it is just a wrapper.

Comment: Does this also work if you read daily data from Google Drive?

Comment: Yes using external tools e.g. rclone mount